# Getting Week end date with DATEADD function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I am using the below code to find the week ending date of sign_up_date - a date column that I have.

```
DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, sign_up_date), CAST(sign_up_date AS DATE))
as weekend_date
```

This query is giving me the following result:

| sign_up_date | weekend_date |
| --- | --- |
| 05-09-2012 | 09-09-2012 12:00:00 AM |
| 09-09-2012 | 16-09-2012 12:00:00 AM |

Is there a way for me to get the weekend_date to end on Sunday, i.e., 10-09-2012 12:00:00 AM.

OR in another way so that the date 09-09-2012 actually gets the weekend_date as 09-09-2012

Comment: DATEADD() is not a standard function in PostgreSQL. You could use a + to add some interval: SELECT current_date + 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured the following code works better for my purpose.

```
TO_DATE (sign_up_date, 'IYYY-IW') as weekend_date
```

This gets me the weekend date based on ISO which is what I wanted in the first place.